# Mapping .txt in talend

Tags: database, automation, etl, talend

How to map the first 2 rows from a .txt file into a database in talend. 
Right now mapping csv files work, however since I dont have headers in the .txt file how can I map it 
This is what I did so far. I dont know what to do with the tfileinputdelimited in order to extract the first 2 lines from a .txt file (it doesn't have headers) and also I want this to be automated (through file watcher)

The columns dont show in the mapping 
[image]

Comment: Hi Zuhair, Can you please elaborate where the problem is exactly? You can use tfileinputdelimited to get the rows by specifying the extension as txt and changing the Field Separator to the one that you have rather than comma.

Comment: I solved this problem ..... but could you please help me with another one .. Ive noticed that you're expert in ETL and its really urgent

Comment: Mapping FK into a table in talend
https://stackoverflow.com/q/55000217/10962023?sem=2