# Mapping FK into a table in talend

Tags: database, automation, foreign-keys, etl, talend

I have 2 entities in my schema. I mapped one already and now for the second one I need to also have the PK of the first entity as a FK in the second entity when mapping using talend. They are both in the same job, but how can I use the Pk of the first entity in the mapping of the second entity?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVl0G.png)

This is what I have so far (row1 is entity1 which has an autogenerated key inside the tmap)

row2 is creating csv from xml file 
row3 maps the csv file generated from row2, however it should have a fk from entity 1 that is from row1

Comment: Someone please answer! Thanks

Comment: I don't know if this is what you are looking for but you can use the tSetGlobalVar or tJavaRow to set a global variable to be used anywhere. But my concern would be that you can only save one value there and things will override one another. What do you mean that the key from row1 one will be used on row2? If you have multiple files parsed in row1, then row1 and row2 should be connected to iterate on every entry.

Comment: By rows I mean the logic in each line shown in the picture above. Like the things in the first line are row1 etc. I tried to use global variable and set a database input before it. I thought of getting the count of rows in a database and then incrementing +1 to the global variable, that could be the Fk in entity2 since entity1 Pk is autoincrememnted but the number stays 1 for all rows (doesn't increment)

Comment: All the lines in the job above (in the picture) are executed together but the process is done automatically *through a file watcher). could I use global variable, session or anything? If yes could you please show me, since Ive been trying and nothing is working,,, this is my hope :)

Comment: I also tried connecting both inputdelimited into the same tmap, and into 2 dboutput, but the problem is that when we connect both files into the same tmap they become under the same sub job and by that when I run it only one filewatcher path works and the other doesn't

Answer (score 0):

In the tMap_1, create another output row and write the auto generated ID's to a CSV using a tfileOutputDelimeted component. In your tMap_2, lookup this CSV file with the auto generated ID's and write to the table.

[image: Job Design]

Comment: but im using file watcher for both. So when I link the lookup file they all become under one sub job and only one filewatcher runs when I run talend

Comment: They will still remain as different subjobs. Use a tfileOutputDelimeted component to write the generated ID's from tMap_1. Then use a new tfileInputDelimeted component to read the generated ID's in your tMap_2.

Comment: Check my edit. That's how the design will look like. The file path and schema should be the same for tfileOutputDelimeted and tfileInputDelimeted

Comment: but shouldn't the tfileinputdelimited be connected to a filewatcher, so that we look for the file each time its added.. then ill face the same problem above with the file watchers in the same sub job

Comment: No you don't have to add a file watcher. Just link the tWaitForFile_1 with tWaitForFile_2 with subJobok (Right click on tWaitForFile_1 -> On SubJobok -> link it to  tWaitForFile_2 ). Do the same from tWaitForFile_2 to tWaitForFile_3